# Sharepoint date difference formula

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a problem in Sharepoint 2010. I have a list with two columns, [Start date] and [End date]. I've made a new column, a calculated field, in which I want to see the difference between the two dates, like "8h 34m" (hours and minutes only). The problem is that [End date] could be empty, so this new column should be empty as well, if that's the case. The formula I used has errors, and I can not find another one. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISBLANK([End date]),"",[End date]-[Start date])
```